# Can tcs3200 be interfaced with msp430? If yes then how?

Tags: microcontroller

I am using tcs3200 in my protean I am confused about which controller can I use other then arduino. Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Welcome to EESE. However, please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask(https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to determine  the output frequency. You need a timer which probably any microcontroller available has at least one. So, yes you can.

Comment: Can you please help to with the connections?